# X*Z has same distribution of Y*Z?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose I have three r.v.s $X, Y, Z$ such that $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed.

Can we say that $X\cdot Z$ and $Y\cdot Z$ have the same distribution? Can we prove it or disprove it?

Note: $X, Y, Z$ may be continuous r.v. and may be not necessarily be independent.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly they can have the same distribution, for example if all three are independent. But they do not have to have the same distribution

For example, let $X=1$ or $-1$ each with probability $\frac12$, $Y=-X$ and $Z=X$.  All three have the same distribution.  Then $XZ=1$ with probability $1$ while $YZ=-1$ with probability $1$, so these are different

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a clever answer to a question I didn't realise it was so trivial.

Comment: If they are independent, then they *must* have the same distribution. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @MPW - yes, though are also other examples where $XZ$ and $YZ$ have the same distribution, such as $X=Y$